# How to add limit word in WordPress dashborad

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add limit word this plugin list. I want to show 1 word like "Amar"

row code:

```
<td class="manage-column ss-list-width"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo $row->code; ?> <?php  ?> </a></td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab only the first word of the code using `strstr`:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo strstr($row->code, ' ', true); ?> <?php  ?> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
<td class="manage-column ss-list-width"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo substr($row->code, 0 , length); ?> <?php  ?> </a></td>
```

Comment: with substr he will need to know the length of the first word in advance